# Disabled prop of Checkbox doesn't work in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create Checkbox dynamically in React with Material UI and I want to use the props "disabled" to control with a state. 
But when I create the Checkbox in componentDidMount(), the "disabled" prop doesn't update the state of my Checkbox. When I create the Checkbox directly in render() it works.
Here a example (and CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-lewin-lxmp3?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      edit: false,
      listCheckbox: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let listCheckbox = null;
    listCheckbox = (
      <div>
        <Checkbox disabled={!this.state.edit} />
        Checkbox componentDidMount()<br />
      </div>)

    this.setState({
      listCheckbox: listCheckbox,
    })
  }

  click() {
    this.setState({
      edit: this.state.edit ? false : true
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button
          onClick={this.click.bind(this)}
        >
         Update state!
        </button>

        <Checkbox disabled={!this.state.edit} /> Checkbox render() <br />
        {this.state.listCheckbox}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like that a way that I could use "disabled" prop and create my Checkbox in componentDidMount().
Thanks!

My official project is

```
componentDidMount() {
        ipcRenderer.send("get:menus", {})
        ipcRenderer.once("get:menus:200", (event, menus) => {
            ipcRenderer.send("get:accesshasmenus", {where: { idAccessLevel: this.props.nivelDeAcesso.idAccessLevel }})
            ipcRenderer.once("get:accesshasmenus:200", (event, accessLevelHasMenu) => {
                let listaCheckedMenu = {};
                //Inicializando o estado dos checks dos menus
                menus.map((menu) => {
                    //Para cada menu, verificando se ele está na lista de menus habilitados
                    //Para o idAccessLevel (por meio de accessLevelHasMenu)
                    //Se estiver, checked true, se não, checked false
                    for(let i = 0; i < accessLevelHasMenu.length; i++) {
                        if(accessLevelHasMenu[i].idMenu == menu.idMenu) {
                            listaCheckedMenu[menu.idMenu] = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        listaCheckedMenu[menu.idMenu] = false;
                    }
                })

                this.setState({
                    listaCheckedMenu: listaCheckedMenu,
                    listaMenus: menus,
                    listaAccessLevelHasMenu: accessLevelHasMenu,
                    conteudoListaMenus: (
                        menus.map((menu) => (
                            <div key={menu.idMenu}>
                                <Checkbox
                                    defaultChecked={listaCheckedMenu[menu.idMenu]}
                                    disabled={!this.state.modoEdicao}
                                    checked={this.state.listaCheckedMenu[menu.idMenu]}
                                    onChange={this.handleChangeChecked.bind(this, menu.idMenu)}
                                    color="default"
                                /> {menu.label} <br/>
                            </div>
                        ))
                    )
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--you create a checkbox in `cDM` with the current state of `edit`--are you expecting the component you've created once on mount to be updated later via a state change? That checkbox is in state--it's not going to be re-created.

Comment: I want that when I clicked the button, my Checkedbox be disabled and enable. I can do this with the CheckBox that I created in render() method. But the Checkbox that I created (in the exact same way) in cDM doesn't change. You can try in CodeSandBox. I try in my program and the "checked" prop, when I use a state in a CheckBox made in CDM it's update. Why "disabled" not?

Comment: It's not created "in the exact same way" -- it's created with the current state, once, in `cDM`. `cDM` runs only when the component is mounted. If things need to happen in *render* then it *should* be handled in `render`, although it could be put into an auxiliary method. I think you've misunderstood the component lifecycle--only `render` is called on state/prop changes.

Comment: But "checked" prop, when I use a state, if I change in anywhere of my code, it's update my CheckBox to be checked or unchecked. Why couldn't I do with the "disabled"?

Comment: That's not correct. If you created a checkbox in `cDM` with a "checked" property from state, then change that state somewhere in the code, the component created in `cDM` will not update the way you're claiming.

Comment: So... What could I do to create the CheckBox dynamically? There is no way?

Comment: The way you're doing it where it works (but again, could be extracted to a method or its own component or whatever, depending on your actual requirements). That said: I would recommend reading up on the component lifecycle, state management, and maybe a tutorial or two, because there seem to be some high-level misconceptions. Things will be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I read the question wrongly the first time... I'll answer better this time.

So, I've changed the code and I think this is the best way this can be done using react.

Creating a component as a part of the state and then dynamically rendering won't work well. You might get ti to work eventually but it's not how react hopes you will be using components and state. Instead, try to pass data and properties to the render and there conditionally make some action.

I've changed the code and done this... Explanation below the code

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      edit: false,
      isChecked: false,
      listCheckbox: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      listCheckbox: ["Checkbox 1", "Checkbox 2"]
    })
  }

  click() {
    this.setState({
      edit: this.state.edit ? false : true
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { listCheckbox } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Update state!</button> <br />
        {
          listCheckbox.map((label) => {
            return <div>
              <Checkbox 
                checked={this.state.isChecked}
                disabled={!this.state.edit}
                onClick={() => this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked})}
              />
              {label} 
            </div>
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Do you see the main change there?

The render function knows all time what components it's working with and what to do when the data changes... This will make the component simpler to maintain and more legible for the people in your team

Comment: It's just debug/info text in the checkbox component created in `cDM`.

Comment: Ya, I think you should try to read my question and try my CodeBox first....

Comment: @MagriniBruna if you don't understand what I mean here, let me know :) I'll try to explain better

Comment: Thank you, Alejandro! It works! I needed some time to realized I could use ipcRenderer in componentDidMount() and in the render() method I could use the states. But I finally get it. Thanks :)